# why doesn't the browser redirect when using a status of 410 in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

Some of my products have been removed from my store.

I thought it was natural to do this for all of these products that might still get traffic from search engine links:

```
redirect_to :root, :status => 410
```

Curiously, rails seems to send back a You are being redirected body, instead of an actual redirect.

However

```
redirect_to :root
```

Works as expected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`410` is client error response (resource gone), not a redirect response.

Only [`3xx` status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) are redirects.